# Linear algebra. Functional analysis.

Tags: linear-algebra

For which a set of vectors in three-dimensional space, the coordinates of which are given by the equations $$x + y + z = 0, \\ 3(x + 4)-a = 0$$, is a linear subspace in the linear space of all vectors?

I know that a subset of $A$ is a subspace of a linear space $M$, it must also be a linear space and it is necessary and sufficient that the operations of addition and multiplication by a number do not lead beyond the limits of this subset. How can I show this? First prove the axioms of a linear space?

Comment: It can help the process to state the requirements for a space to be a linear space and subspace.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the question. I guess the question is for which values of $a$, the set of vectors defined by the above equations is a subspace of three-dim space. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Hint: show and use the fact that the origin needs to lie in every subspace.

Comment: How i can do the equation? Yep Wonko, you understood correctly.